# Reduce quality in Netflix for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, applications

My 3G can't seem to handle Netflix streaming; it stops to buffer constantly.

The quality seems to be way too high -- it seems to be trying to do HD, without the connection for it.

Is there a way to lower the quality, down to maybe YouTube-level, so I can actually stream anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Since a lot of providers have bandwidth caps, Netflix has put in a downgrade quality option to manage video quality.

Login to netflix first, then go to
https://account.netflix.com/HdToggle

Select from

- Good Quality.  up to 0.3 GB per hour.
- Better Quality.  Up to 0.7 GB per hour.
- Best Quality.  Up to 1 GB per hour, or 2.3 GB per hour for
  HD.

Comment: This works...ish There's no option to select the downgrade just for your phone. It will downgrade ALL your netflix streaming.